# How to overcome plugin errors in android studio installation

Tags: java, android-studio

I have trying to install android studio on my pc and after instaliing and tring to launch it I was encountered with following error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

I have tried several solutions obtained from the internet searches, but none of them could solve the issue